# Conditional Mandatory in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, parameter-sets, validateset

I'm trying to make a parameter mandatory, but only if another parameter uses certain ValidateSet values.  It seems that using a code block on Mandatory doesn't work as expected.

```
function Test-Me {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateSet("NameRequired", "AlsoRequired")]
        [string]
        $Type = "NoNameRequired",

        [Parameter(Mandatory = {-not ($Type -eq "NoNameRequired")})]
        [string]
        $Name
    )

    Process {
        Write-Host "I ran the process block."
        Write-Host "Type = '$Type'"
        Write-Host "Name = '$Name'"
        Write-Host "Name Parameter Mandatory? = '$(-not ($Type -eq "NoNameRequired"))'"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

function Test-Me {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "Gorgonzola")]
    Param (

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [int]
        $Number,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = "NameNeeded")]
        [ValidateSet("NameRequired", "AlsoRequired")]
        [string]
        $Type = "NoNameRequired",

        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = "NameNeeded")]
        [string]
        $Name
    )

    Process {
        Write-Host "I ran the process block."
        Write-Host "Number = '$Number'"
        Write-Host "Type = '$Type'"
        Write-Host "Name = '$Name'"
        Write-Host "Name Parameter Mandatory = '$(-not ($Type -eq "NoNameRequired"))'"
    }
}
```

Parameter sets seem to help simulate conditional mandatory parameters.

I can make it to where if either the **Type** or **Name** parameter is given, then they are both required.  This can happen regardless of other parameters in the function, such as the sibling **Number** parameter above.

I set the default parameter set name to something random; I usually specify "None".  That parameter set name doesn't need to actually exist, again indicated by the Number parameter.

All of this works regardless of your strict mode setting.

Comment: You could also look at Dynamic Parameters. They could make your code look shorter, but are a little more confusing.

Comment: Neat!  I hadn't heard of dynamic parameters, they look helpful.